# It seems my filament is burnt when I use PETG

Tags: prusa-i3

I use the Cura; nylon default(recommended) settings for PETG. Upon my filament's box is written 200-240 for nozzle and 75-85 for bed. So I tried 245/80 - 220/80 - 220/60 - 245/60.

But I got same result as you can see in the pics:

[image]

[image]

My printer is PrusaI3 (actually a chinese kit that I assembled it myself). Also I had good print results with PLA before this. I was using 190/50 for PLA).

Comment: Good question.  I see signs of uneven extrusion (blobbiness), or perhaps bad bed adhesion, but it is hard to tell from the pictures.  Is there one full, even layer (I see a nice smooth coloration around the print)?

Comment: @cmm: the support layers are very nice and smooth but the problem is about center layers. I will change the Teflon today and hope it will solve.

Comment: Have you had this result more than once, or only this one time?  @Mick answer is pretty likely if this is the first and only time.  If you've reproduced this more than once, the problem could be elsewhere.  Do you have a direct-drive extruder or Bowden?  If direct drive, you might be heating the drive wheel so that the grip is not strong enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a clogged nozzle/hot end. I use 225°C @ 40mm/s for PETG with 235°C @ 30mm/s for the first layer.

If you print at 245°C, you risk burning the PTFE liner in your hot end. You really need an all-metal hot end to print at such temperatures.

It is possible that you have already damaged the PTFE liner, and this may be the cause of your problem. However, I would check for a clogged nozzle first.